# how to know the status of lambda in java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, monitoring

I have an lambda which is running on multiple aws instances, Now,I have an requirement to get the status of lambda (whether it is running or not)  in-order to find the number of active instances using java . 
Can anyone please suggest me some solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a concurrency limit for the lambda, you will have the [`ConcurrentExecutions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html) metric that

> "Measures the sum of concurrent executions for a given function at a
>   given point in time."